# MATLAB change the values of ylabel as depth

Tags: matlab, depth

I have the following script

```
clear all; clc;close all;

dx = 0:100:400 % in meters
rho_30 = [ 33.2185   33.3202   33.4763   33.5851   33.6078];


rho_50 = [ 58.4567   58.1212   57.5382   56.8300   56.0449];


rho_70 = [76.1825   76.0842   75.9825   75.9252   75.9507];

plot(dx,rho_30, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2) % rho at depth = 30 meters

hold on

plot(dx,rho_50, 'b', 'LineWidth', 2) % rho at depth = 50 meters

hold on

plot(dx,rho_70, 'g', 'LineWidth', 2) % rho at depth = 70 meters

grid on

legend('rho at depth = 30m', 'rho at depth = 50m', 'rho at depth = 70m')

xlabel('length of channel (meters)'); ylabel('depth(meters)')
```

As you can see from the plot, the depth is started from 80m at surface until 30 m at bottom.

My question: How to change that the depth should be started from -30 at the
surface until -80 meters at the bottom or ylabel should be started
from -30 until -80

Comment: you mean the `xticks` and `xticklabels` ? or the label itself?

Comment: ylabel should be -30 at surface and -80 at bottom, at the same time rho_30 (red) should be put at the top, rho_50 (blue) middle and rho_70 (green) at the bottom.

Comment: Why not just plot `-rho_30`, `-rho_50` and `-rho_70` instead of `rho_30`, `rho_50` and `rho_70`?

Comment: Luis Mendo, the results will be wrong. The blue one, for e.g. will be increasing.

Comment: I am sorry... You are right Luis Mendo. The blue one should be increasing now after the ylabel is reversed. Thanks a lot Luis Mendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flip the direction of the Y-axis, you can do:

```
set(gca,'YDir','reverse');
```

`gca` returns a handle to the current axes object. In this `set` command you are setting the the y-axis direction (`'YDir'`) to `'reverse'` (as opposed to the default value of `'normal'`).

Comment: Thanks KQS. It works but how to change 30 to be -30 and 80 to be -80?

Comment: You can use @Luis Mendo's suggestion (plot `-rho_30` etc.). This will change everything to be negative. And then you can flip the Y-axis direction if needed.

Comment: If you really want to change the y-axis tick labels instead of the data, you can do `set(gca, 'YTick',[30 40 50 60 70 80], 'YTickLabel',{'-30','-40','-50','-60','-70','-80'})`, but it's kinda cumbersome and is easy to make a mistake.